# Passing NSManagedObject thread safe since iOS 10?

Tags: swift, core-data

I now work in a new app that just started development. We are trying to achieve the best performance out of the new Core Data, as described in WWDC 2016 lecture about Core Data, or how it is translated here: http://holko.pl/2016/06/23/core-data/

Our main question is whether we can now pass NSManagedObject's with still maintaining thread safety. As explained in the lecture and article, the new Query generation model lets us pass around objects straight from the DB into our code, (without parsing them and only then passing them around).

Regardless to that question, we are searching to understand whether the improvements in Core data are something that is only happening behind the scene, and we should just enjoy its fruits, or we need to learn certain techniques on how to get the best out of the new features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSManagedObject` is not thread-safe.  There are new features of query generation which you can learn to use to do cool stuff, but it is not automatic and does not give you thread safety.  See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/242/

Comment: Thanks, can you please refer me to how to search for these techniques? any name/link/snippets will be very much appreciated.

Comment: I updated my answer.  I do not believe that query generation will give you thread safety.  If you want thread safety you should copy the values from the managed object into your own object (an NSObject subclass)

Comment: Your link is the video I was referring to in the question :) Anyways, just so I understand you correctly, the only way is to parse the NSManagedObject into another object of my own if I want to pass it around?

Comment: As far as I know.